# JQuery Selector for recurring element with in same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below Html Structure

> Existing

```html
    <fieldset>
        ....
        <div>
           <div class="responsive"></div>
        </div>
        ...
        <fieldset>
            ....
            <div class="responsive"></div>
        </fieldset>
        ...
        <div class="responsive"></div>
        <fieldset>
        <div>
           <div class="responsive"></div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive"></div>
    <fieldset>
        .....
        <div class="responsive"></div>
        <div class="responsive"></div>
        <fieldset>
            ........
            <div class="responsive"></div>
            <fieldset>
                    ........
                <div class="responsive"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive"></div>
```

> **EDIT**
>   1) .responsive may have any no. of parents till fieldset
>
> 2) between .reponsive and fieldset they may have any siblings in below and after

i need to write the JQuery selector to find .responsive with in fieldset but to 1st level only so that i should fix width. i.e

```
fieldset -> .responsive (correct) (result may contain 1 or more)
fieldset -> .responsive -> fieldset -> .responsive (wrong)
.responsive (wrong)
```

But through this selector i should be able to select all .responsive div's with in fieldset only and keep width to it.

> Expected Output

```html
    <fieldset>
        ....
        <div>
           <div class="responsive" style="width:xpx;"></div>
        </div>
        ...
        <fieldset>
            ....
            <div class="responsive" style="width:yzpx;"></div>
        </fieldset>
        ...
        <div class="responsive"></div>
        <fieldset>
        <div>
           <div class="responsive" style="width:xypx;"></div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive"></div>
    <fieldset>
        .....
        <div class="responsive" style="width:xzpx;"></div>
        <div class="responsive" style="width:zpx;"></div>
        <fieldset>
            ........
            <div class="responsive" style="width:xzpx;"></div>
            <fieldset>
                    ........
                <div class="responsive" style="width:yzpx;"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried `$("fieldset > .responsive")`?

Comment: hi vijay, let me try if this suits my requirement, please check the expected output too as i just added

Comment: hello Pavan, i have added the snippet so that you can test it here itself.

Comment: mentioned 2 of the many methods below. let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi i have updated the scenario in EDIT section now please check this once

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("fieldset > .responsive").css("background", "gray").text("width:xyzpx;");
});
```

```css
.responsive {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  1<div class="responsive"></div>
  <fieldset>
    2<div class="responsive"></div>
  </fieldset>
  3<div class="responsive"></div>
  <fieldset>
    4<div class="responsive"></div>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
5<div class="responsive"></div>
<fieldset>
  6<div class="responsive"></div>
  7<div class="responsive"></div>
  <fieldset>
    8<div class="responsive"></div>
    <fieldset>
      9<div class="responsive"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
10<div class="responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Hi i have updated the Existing HTML and written EDIT Section points Please check once

Comment: @PavanKosanam - i am sure above code will work for you. Please test it at your end and let me know. Just updated the code to put text inside targeted `div`. Utilize it as per your need.

Comment: i may not have .responsive in immediate child

Comment: `find .responsive with in fieldset but to 1st level only` this and `i may not have .responsive in immediate child` these 2 statements are totally opposite to each other.

Comment: sorry if i mis guided you, my intension is (fieldset .-. - .- .responsive not fieldset .-.-..fieldset  - .- .responsive)

Comment: @PavanKosanam - its somewhat confusing to me. could you please update your expected output or tell me which div number is incorrect in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**This would select all the `.responsive` elements which is under `<fieldset>` but at the same time NOT under any 2nd level `<fieldset>`.**

1) using the CSS selector like so

```
$("fieldset :not(fieldset) .responsive").css("width", "xyzpx");
```

**In the snippet I have mentioned `background-color`** for an example.

```js
$("fieldset :not(fieldset) .responsive").css("background-color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
        <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="responsive" style="width:xyzpx;"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Hi i have updated the Existing HTML and written EDIT Section points Please check once

Comment: So basically it can come anywhere within the `<fieldset>`. Then in the "**Method 1**" just remove the `>` sign. Simple. & in "**Method 2**" remove the `first()` method. Updated answer.

Comment: Then it is selecting the .responsive in this case (fieldset -> fieldset -> .responsive), i want only direct .responsive

Comment: Hmm so **you want the `.responsive` within a <fieldset>, where that fieldset has no parent** ? I am right ?

Comment: yes i want .responsive within a fieldset which has no other fieldset in between these two

Comment: According to your 'Expected output' above that is what you want (fieldset -> fieldset -> .responsive). All your .responsive inside any fieldset has the width. Can you edit if its incorrect

Comment: Just now Updated the Expected output

Comment: Your "Expected Output" is still **not in sync** with what you want..according to the expected you still want to select **(fieldset -> fieldset -> .responsive)**, but what you are telling over comments is that don't want that.

Comment: @PavanKosanam - Check my answer please, I think I got what you want now :-)

Comment: Hi your selector $("fieldset :not(fieldset) .responsive") is giving 

**fieldset -> .responsive** (this)



fieldset -> **.fieldset -> .responsive** (but not this)

Comment: Ofcourse because you just said this -- "**yes i want .responsive within a fieldset which has no other fieldset in between these two**". read you own comment in this chain above.

Comment: but (fieldset -> fieldset -> .responsive), here first and last has in middle(fieldset) , but middle and last didn't have it

Comment: Sorry buddy but your not making it clear what is correct & what is not. Your confusing all of us. **Your "Expected Output" too is completely different from what your requirement over comments is**. I suggest you take some time to document a proper understandable question to help others & yourself.